# Command history but only for one directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, history

Is it possible to get the history of all commands that were entered but just from one folder?

like the

```
history
```

command, but only output should only show commands that the user entered while in a  certain directory

From my knowledge its not possible, but it came up in a meeting today and I would like to make 100% before telling my project manager hes foolish.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: That would imply that you only care about  `rm -rf *` when it is preceded at some point by a `cd /path/to/dir` and don't care when a user does `rm -rf /path/to/dir/` which seems very silly. - Having said that, when you configure  `auditd` to record all commands, it will also record the current working directory `cwd` and you can use that to filter out the commands that were issued from a specific directory.

Comment: Yes I agree, it does seem silly.... your reply is very similar to the argument I put forward during my meeting today, I suspect that in future there will be some scope creep to include `rm -rf /path/to/dir/` also, but for now, I do wish to only find code `rm -rf *` from inside the dir Thanks for the suggestion, I found this  http://access.redhat.com/solutions/49257 which may be suitable, I will report back with results, thanks again –